# How to validate a URL field with AJAX form

Tags: php, ajax, forms, validation

I created a simple ajax form based on this [tutorial](http://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Ajax-Post-to-PHP-File-XMLHttpRequest-Object-Return-Data-Tutorial) and everything works nicely. The only issue I have is that I can't figure out how to validate the data of a URL field. It seems that even though I set the field type as URL it still processes if it's not a URL.

Any ideas?

**example.html**

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
function ajax_post(){
    // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "my_parse_file.php";
    var dlink = document.getElementById("dirtylink").value;
   var vars = "dlink="+dlink;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
      var return_data = hr.responseText;
   document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
     }
    }
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Ajax Post to PHP and Get Return Data</h2>
<input id="dlink" name="dlink" class="putfield" type="url" pattern="https?://.+" required name="website">
<input name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Submit Data" onclick="ajax_post();"> <br><br>
<div id="status"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**my_parse_file.php**

```
<?php 
echo 'Thank you '. $_POST['firstname'] . ' ' . $_POST['lastname'] . ', says 
the PHP file';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

These tags are not valid/standard HTML tags :

- type="url"
- pattern="https?://.+"
- required

Write your html input like this :

```
<input id="dlink" name="dlink" class="putfield" type="text" value="http://"/>
```

(dlink or website you want to name it !?)

Then you have to first validate/control careful all your inputs on the server side, so in `my_parse_file.php` :

```
<?php
//unescape data if magic quotes is activated
function strip(&$str) {
    if(!is_array($str)) { $str = stripslashes($str); }
    }
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc() || get_magic_quotes_runtime()) {
    array_walk($_GET, 'strip');
    array_walk($_POST, 'strip');
    }

//init vars
if(isset($_POST['dlink'])) { $dlink = trim($_POST['dlink']); }else{ $dlink = ''; }

//tiny protect against code injection (XSS)
//maybe need to be revised, with eventual addslashes(), depanding on what you do with $dlink
$dlink = strip_tags($dlink);

//protect against multiline injection
if(preg_match('`^([^\r\n]*)`', $dlink, $match)) { $dlink = $match[1]; }

//control is a right url, can need a little improvement for the right domain format
if(!preg_match('`^(http[s]?://.+)`i', $dlink)) { echo "error"; exit(); }

echo 'Thank you! the url is '.$dlink.', says the PHP file';
?>
```

Then you can add the JS control on the client side, to be more responsive and avoid an http request if bad dlink :

```
var dlink = document.getElementById("dlink").value;
if(!dlink.match(/^http[s]?:\/\/.+/gi)) { alert("url not valid"); return 0; }
var vars = "dlink="+dlink;
```

> Be careful with your direct echo $_POST['varname'] that are not
>   secure.

It seems `filter_var()` can do the job too for control a URL like said by Silvio.

---

### --- UPDATE ---

Next to my answer, I wanted to do some kind of alternative to `filter_var()` by hand and looking for the easiest way to protect the `$_POST` and `$_GET "echo"` against injection.

I don't very approve how `filter_var()` validate/sanitize the URL, because why would I want to record/select in my database an URL that contain injection like "`domain.com<script>alert(cookie)</script>`" or even display to the client "`this url is domain.comalert(cookie)`".

So here is what I have done :

```php
function safe_char($str) {
    $buf = '';
    $enable = array(
        9 => 1,//\t
        10 => 1,//\n
        13 => 1//\r
        );
    $len = mb_strlen($str);
    $i = 0;
    while($i < $len) {
        $ascii = ord($str[$i]);
        //remove unwelcome char, about decimal 0-31 and 127, keep only \t \r \n
        if($ascii !== 127/*DEL*/ && ($ascii > 31 || isset($enable[$ascii]))) {
            $buf .= $str[$i];
            }
        $i++;
        }
    return $buf;
    }

function safe_strip_tags($str, $remove_hack=false, $log_hack=false) {
    if($remove_hack) {
        //$str_ini = $str;

        //remove tag content only when tags script/noscript detected
        $str = preg_replace('`<[[:space:]]*(script|noscript)[^>]*>(.*?<[[:space:]]*/\1[[:space:]]*>|.+)`is', '', $str);

        //logs hack
        //if($log_hack && $str !== $str_ini) {
        //  logs(array('try injection', $str_ini));
        //  }
        }
    //safe delete tags
    $str = strip_tags($str);
    //delete the last unique > or <
    $str = preg_replace('`[<>]+`s', '', $str);
    return $str;
    }

function safe_write($str) {
    //replace by the html entities the critical char that cause injection works
    $char = array('&', '<', '>', '"', '\'');
    $replace = array('&amp;', '&lt;', '&gt;', '&quot;', '&apos;');
    return str_replace($char, $replace, $str);
    }

function filter_url($str, &$url=false, $strict=false) {
    $err = true;
    $str = trim($str);

    //remove unwelcome control char (about from x00 to x1F), it keep only \t \r \n
    $str = safe_char($str);

    //remove html tag and protect against injection (XSS)
    $url = safe_strip_tags($str, true, true);

    //protect against multiline injection
    if(preg_match('`^([^\r\n]*)`', $url, $match)) { $url = $match[1]; }

    //test is like an url
    if(!preg_match('`^(http|ftp)[s]?://.+`i', $url)) {
        //and reject other scheme
        if($url !== '' && mb_strpos($url, '://') === false) {
            //maybe case "www.url.com" so try add an http scheme
            $url = 'http://'.$url;
            $err = false;
            }
        }
    else{ $err = false; }

    //going to confirm url have valid domain
    if(!$err) {
        //remove char that we dont want in an url
        $url = preg_replace('`[\t]+`', '', $url);

        $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
        if($host != null) {
            //no special char in domain name
            if(!preg_match('`^[a-z0-9._-]+$`i', $host)) { $err = true; }

            //no double dot in domain name
            if(!$err && mb_strpos($host, '..') !== false) { $err = true; }

            //domain name
            if(!$err && !preg_match('`[a-z0-9_-]{1,63}\.[a-z.]{2,10}$`i', $host)) { $err = true; }

            //local dev for http://localhost
            //if($err && preg_match('`^[a-z0-9_-]{1,63}$`i', $host)) { $err = false; }

            //more strict controls
            if(!$err) {
                $xpl = explode('.', $host);
                foreach($xpl as $v) {
                    //label not more long than 63 char
                    if(mb_strlen($v) > 63) { $err = true; break; }
                    //label must start with a letter
                    //if(preg_match('`^[0-9]+`', $v)) { $err = true; break; }
                    //label with underscore is normally not valid
                    //if(mb_strpos($v, '_') !== false) { $err = true; break; }
                    }
                }

            //ip
            if($err && preg_match('`^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$`', $host)) { $err = false; }
            //its enough, and not so restricted for the future, if you really want to ctrl an url, you have to request it
            }

        //bad host
        else{ $err = true; }
        }

    //url have been modified
    if($strict && $str !== $url) {
        $err = true;
        }

    if($err) { $url = false; }
    else{ return true; }
    return false;
    }

function filter_string($str, &$string=false, $strict=false) {
    $str = trim($str);
    $string = safe_char($str);//filter_var() cannot do that, so no php_filter_string()
    //string have been modified
    if($strict && $str !== $string) {
        return false;
        }
    return true;
    }
```

Please share with us if you found an injection/bug or optimize it...

**Test the homemade filter_url() results :**

```php
//i writted the result from filter_url() in each comment
$arr = array(
    'https://url.com',//https://url.com
    'http://url.com',//http://url.com
    'http://url.com/test',//http://url.com/test
    'http://url.com/test.php?param=a\'b \"c*&plus=1',//http://url.com/test.php?param=a'b \"c*&plus=1
    'http://url.com/\'t"e*s t',//http://url.com/'t"e*s t
    'http://urlcom',//FALSE
    'http://urlcom/url.com',//FALSE
    'http://url.com\test',//FALSE
    'http://url.com\'"*',//FALSE
    'http://url.c\'"*',//FALSE
    'http://url.\'"*',//FALSE
    '',//FALSE
    'u',//FALSE
    'u.co',//http://u.co
    'http://',//FALSE
    'http://u',//FALSE
    'http://u.c',//FALSE
    'http://u.co',//http://u.co
    'http://ur.co',//http://ur.co
    'http://www.url.com',//http://www.url.com
    'http://www.url',//http://www.url
    'http://url_url.com',//http://url_url.com
    'http://www.thislabelistoolongthislabelistoolongthislabelistoolongthislabelistoolong.com',//FALSE
    'http://localhost',//FALSE
    'http://4url.com',//http://4url.com
    'http://sub.sub.url.com',//http://sub.sub.url.com
    'http://l.s.s.url.com',//http://l.s.s.url.com
    'http://127.0.0.1',//http://127.0.0.1
    'http://127.0.0.1.2',//FALSE
    'http://127.0.0',//FALSE
    'http://127.0.0.1/filter/',//http://127.0.0.1/filter/
    'http://127.0.0.url',//http://127.0.0.url
    'http://127.url',//http://127.url
    'http://url.127',//FALSE
    'http://u27.c27',//FALSE
    'http://u27.com',//http://u27.com
    'http://127.0.0.1:80/filter/',//http://127.0.0.1:80/filter/
    'http://127.0.0.1.2:80/filter/',//FALSE
    'http://1278.0.0.1.2:80/filter/',//FALSE
    'ftps://127.0.0.1:80/filter/',//ftps://127.0.0.1:80/filter/
    'ftp://url.com',//ftp://url.com
    'javascript://comment%0Aalert(1)',//FALSE
    'javascript://url.com',//FALSE
    'www.url.com',//http://www.url.com
    'http://url..com',//FALSE
    'http://url.com..com',//FALSE
    'http://url.com/te..st',//http://url.com/te..st
    'http://url.com/test?param=%0D%0A%61%62',//http://url.com/test?param=%0D%0A%61%62
    'http://url.com/'."\r\n".'multiline',//http://url.com/
    'http://url.com/'."\n".'multiline',//http://url.com/
    'http://url.com/x<i; j>y; >>',//http://url.com/xy; 
    'http://url.com/<tag<one>two>text',//http://url.com/text
    'http://url.com/<tag<one>two>text<three>',//http://url.com/text
    'http://url.com/"><script>alert(cookie)</script>',//http://url.com/"
    'http://url.com/%0D%0A<script>alert(cookie)</script>',//http://url.com/%0D%0A
    'http://url.com/%0D%0A<script>alert(cookie)path/',//http://url.com/%0D%0A
    'http://url.com/<strong onload="alert(cookie)">txt</strong>',//http://url.com/txt
    'http://url.com/<   space   >text',//http://url.com/spacetext
    'http://url.com/<xxx script yyy>txt</script>',//http://url.com/txt
    'http://url.com/%3Ctag%3Cone%3Etwo%3Etext%3Cthree%3E',//http://url.com/%3Ctag%3Cone%3Etwo%3Etext%3Cthree%3E
    'http://url.com/%0D%0A%3Cscript%3Ealert(cookie)%3C/script%3E',//http://url.com/%0D%0A%3Cscript%3Ealert(cookie)%3C/script%3E
    'http://url.com/canbenice%0D%0A%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E%61%6C%65%72%74%28%63%6F%6F%6B%69%65%29%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E',//http://url.com/canbenice%0D%0A%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E%61%6C%65%72%74%28%63%6F%6F%6B%69%65%29%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E
    //'http://url.co�m/charctrl',//http://url.com/charctrl
    );
$charctrl = '';
$i = 0;
while($i < 32) {
    if($i!==9 && $i!==10 && $i!==13) {
        $charctrl .= chr($i);
        }
    $i++;
    }
$charctrl .= chr(127);
$arr[] = 'http://url.co'.$charctrl.'m/charctrl';

echo '<pre>';
foreach($arr as $v) {
    echo $v.' => ';
    if(filter_url($v, $url)) { echo $url; }else{ echo 'FALSE'; }
    echo "\r\n";
    }
echo '</pre>';

echo "\r\n\r\n".'<br/><br/>'."\r\n\r\n";

echo '<pre>';
foreach($arr as $v) {
    echo $v.' => ';
    if(php_filter_url($v, $url)) { echo $url; }else{ echo 'FALSE'; }
    echo "\r\n";
    }
echo '</pre>';
```

**filter_var() solution :**
Sorry for my lack of not knowing these filter_var() functions...
The function has a little ambiguous name, but it is finally safe when used right, so be careful choosing the right id/flag.

- FILTER_VALIDATE_URL is not intended to protect you against injection, it just control if it can be an url.
- FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING have to be applied to protect against XSS when you display the var.

```php
function php_filter_url($str, &$url=false, $strict=false) {
    $err = true;
    $str = trim($str);
    $url = $str;

    //protect against multiline injection
    if(preg_match('`^([^\r\n]*)`', $url, $match)) { $url = $match[1]; }

    //add this because FILTER_VALIDATE_URL accept others scheme
    if(!preg_match('`^(http|ftp)[s]?://.+`i', $url)) {
        //reject other scheme
        if($url !== '' && mb_strpos($url, '://') === false) {
            //maybe case "www.url.com" so try add an http scheme
            $url = 'http://'.$url;
            $err = false;
            }
        }
    else{ $err = false; }

    if(!$err) {
        $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED | FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED);
        if(!$url) { $err = true; }
        }

    if(!$err) {
        $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
        if(!$url) { $err = true; }
        }

    //url have been modified
    if($strict && $str !== $url) {
        $err = true;
        }

    if($err) { $url = false; }
    else{ return true; }
    return false;
    }
```

I mention that im sorry for my "exotic" indentation, I don't like at all the "official", have tried to go back, but impossible... so I can understand what you think about mine :D

**Test `filter_var()` results, alias `php_filter_url()` :**

I let you try the urls test yourself, there are some "false" match, but it looks not so bad, except maybe for these results :

- http://urlcom
- http://url..com
- http://url.comalert(cookie)
- http://127.0.0.1.2

**Bench :**
filter_url() is about 5 times slower than php_filter_url(), and we can about not optimize more without losing easy readable script. But its not a dramatic bench lose. (PHP 5.4)

**Best solution:**
Use the homemade solution if you need to handle the case where filter_var() cannot.
Finally, an URL, even well written and validated, can be a bad URL... you have to request it to really know.
And when someone tries to inject something, I doubt it is with true information, so these "url.comalert(cookie)" are finally useless, the homemade version try to clean it to free space, and can record the injection Infos to logs.
Humm, I just think that maybe we have to not validate vars where the injection is detected...

**About the form:**
For the reason that its not safe to validate the inputs in javascript (client side), you have to handle the eventual error returned by php, to be sure what to do then, in javascript.

Your code example is not well adapted to this situation, because you normally need to use an xml response instead of the actual text response, to right validate "in the art of XHTML" the information in javascript. (and it need much more code/understanding)

So, to stay simple, but very right too, you can go with an alternative like this one :

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.field {
    font-weight:bolder;
    border:2px gray solid;
    color:black;
    }
.fieldError {
    border:2px red solid;
    color:red;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getXhr() {
    var xhr = false;
    try{
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }catch (e){
        try{
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        }catch (e){
            try{
            xhr = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
            }catch (e){
                try{
                xhr = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                }catch (e){
                    alert('Your browser is not compatible with XML request');                           
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return xhr;
    }

function encodeUrl(str) {
    if(encodeURIComponent) { str = encodeURIComponent(str); }
    else if(escape) { str = escape(str); }
    //sure not any = and &
    str = str.replace(/=/gi, "%3D");
    str = str.replace(/&/gi, "%26");
    return str;
    }

function getNodeText(tag, content) {
    var regex = new RegExp('<'+tag+'>(.*?)</'+tag+'>', 'g');
    var match = regex.exec(content);
    return match[1];
    }

function safeWrite(str) {
    str = str.replace(/</g, '&lt;');
    str = str.replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
    str = str.replace(/\"/g, '&quot;');
    str = str.replace(/\'/g, '&apos;');
    return str;
    }

function ajaxPost() {
    var err = false;
    var errMsg = 'Invalid form';

    //init obj
    var dlink = document.getElementById("dlink");
    var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname");

    //reinit input class
    dlink.className = "field";
    firstname.className = "field";

    //test input dlink
    if(!dlink.value.match(/^http[s]?:\/\/.+/gi)) {
        dlink.className = "field fieldError";
        err = true;
        }
    //test input firstname
    if(firstname.value == '') {
        firstname.className = "field fieldError";
        err = true;
        }
    //return directly on error
    if(err) {
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = errMsg;
        return false;
        }

    //create our XMLHttpRequest object
    var xhr = getXhr();
    //create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "my_parse_file.php";
    var param = "dlink="+encodeUrl(dlink.value)+"&firstname="+encodeUrl(firstname.value);
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    //set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    //access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            //alert(xhr.responseText);

            //make our own tiny parser, and get all the response infos
            var dlinkText = getNodeText("dlink", xhr.responseText);
            var dlinkErr = getNodeText("dlinkErr", xhr.responseText);
            var firstnameText = getNodeText("firstname", xhr.responseText);
            var firstnameErr = getNodeText("firstnameErr", xhr.responseText);

            //update var for a more secure/easy int type handle
            dlinkErr = parseInt(dlinkErr, 10);
            firstnameErr = parseInt(firstnameErr, 10);

            //handle the real error returned by php
            if(dlinkErr !== 0) {
                dlink.className = "field fieldError";
                err = true;
                }
            if(firstnameErr !== 0) {
                firstname.className = "field fieldError";
                err = true;
                }

            //form fail
            if(err) { document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = errMsg; }

            //form pass all the test, we recontrol with safeWrite() that there is no code injection
            else{
                var success = 'Thank you '+safeWrite(firstnameText)+'! the url is '+safeWrite(dlinkText);
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = success;
                }
            }
        }
    //send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    xhr.send(param);//actually execute the request
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Ajax Post to PHP and Get Return Data</h2>
<label for="dlink">dlink :</label><input id="dlink" name="dlink" type="text" value="http://" class="field"/><br/>
<label for="firstname">firstname :</label><input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" value="" class="field"/><br/>
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Data" onmouseup="ajaxPost();">
<div id="status"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**my_parse_file.php**

```php
<?php
//force to refresh the cache of the browser
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
header('Pragma: no-cache');

//include our filter functions
include './filter.php';

//init vars
$output = '';
$dlink_err = 0;
$firstname_err = 0;

//control $_POST
if(!isset($_POST['dlink'])) { $_POST['dlink'] = ''; $dlink_err = 1; }//trim is done inside filter functions
if(!isset($_POST['firstname'])) { $_POST['firstname'] = ''; $firstname_err = 1; }

//control/validate dlink is like a valid url, and clean the code injection try
if(!filter_url($_POST['dlink'], $dlink)) { $dlink_err = 1; }
//if(!php_filter_url($_POST['dlink'], $dlink)) { $dlink_err = 1; }//not well cleaned

//control firstname, only remove unwelcome charaters from the string, it can return false only if you use the $strict arg
if(!filter_string($_POST['firstname'], $firstname)) { $firstname_err = 1; }

//validate firstname is not empty
if($firstname === '') { $firstname_err = 1; }

//prepare the response, and protect against injection (XSS) with the help of safe_write()
$output .= '<dlink>'.safe_write($dlink).'</dlink>
<dlinkErr>'.$dlink_err.'</dlinkErr>
<firstname>'.safe_write($firstname).'</firstname>
<firstnameErr>'.$firstname_err.'</firstnameErr>';

echo $output;
?>
```

My first note about "invalid/not standard html tag" is little unclear, they are the valid new tags attribute from HTML5 that date from 2015, but if you use it, your website will be not compatible with "old" client that no support this "new" HTML5. So to create a website that is surely compatible around the world, you have to use the HTML4 and more exactly the XHTML 1.0 that date from 2000.

There is one last thing that is not good in this code, the form is not functionnal if javascript is desactivated.
Normally, the right way creating website is making it work without javascript (at least the main frontend functions), and only then you add the javascript layer.

So, in my opinion, you have take the way in the reverse, so I suggest you restart by firstly create simple php form + validation, and only then you add the js layer.

A tips to avoid writting double validation, is to reuse the same php file validation on two place, 1st in the header of the simple php form, and 2nd in the ajax request (so this validation file is my_parse_file.php in our example, but it need to be modified to handle who posted). I havent write this solution because it dont really answer the asked question that is for using ajax, and we are already on the borderline... :D

*Message in a bottle at SOa :* The "compatible worldwideweb" is like seriously dieing these times, so please all, make it survive creating compatible websites :)

Comment: Thank You! Seems like it works nicely, but alot of code. How is this better than `filter_var()`? One thing though, is it possible to get the "url not valid" error right under the `<input>` box in a `<p>` or something, as opposed to a browser alert? Also, you mentioned "Be careful with your direct echo `$_POST['varname']` that are not secure." Can you please further enlighten me on this issue? Thank you!

Comment: My code is compatible with php4, but finally i think filter_var() will be better for you, because it can normally auto protect you against these injections on url, email, int,... [link](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/filter.filters.validate.php)
And so, you just have to code yourself the filter function to valid a random string (like a firstname/message input), so this function will contain in our example strip_tags(). [link](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/filter.filters.misc.php)

Comment: So, if you are on PHP >= 5.4.0, you can delete the part "unescape data if magic quotes", let the `init vars` control, and just use `filter_var()` with the line from Silvio, then `echo`.

Comment: About the error return, its up to you to replace the alert() by another javascript function, and maybe done a better error handling.
The most easy way, is to create this <p> at the place you want in the html, give it a initial `<p id="dlinkError" class="inputError" style="display:none">`, and then switch his style in JS when error occur, with `document.getElementById("dlinkError").style.display="block";`

Comment: Ok, i was a little alarmist with these direct echo, there is lot of luck/complication that we can hack about nothing just with these direct echo, without other breach somewhere.
But you have to be extremely careful if you record $firstname for example in mysql, and then show this recorded $firstname to other user than the hacker.
Some "new" function from php will auto protect you from the mysql injection, but not from submitting html/js code injection.

Comment: So to avoid problems, the best way is to always control that the submitted inputs contain what you intend to get, filtered without the critical characters, dont thrust any $_POST or $_GET, and only the server side can really control them, javascript can be bypassed because it is on the client side.

Comment: It finally seem filter_var() contain all the filter to do all the filter job safe [link](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/filter.filters.php).
So i suggest you right learn how this function works. Me i have never use it, my answer is to do at the hand what this function do, and its too risky...

Comment: Wow! it seem filter_var() is not so safe, at least for url (maybe it depend of the php version).
Read in the comments of the func [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php).
So finally i will maybe continue using my own filter functions :D
I will try finding the best way to control it and eventually update my answer.

Comment: Im working on it, and i need some more reflection time before release it (max in one week).
You can use what i have posted for the moment, its injection safe (except maybe one case about using $dlink in javascript that i have to review).
But it can contain some extra characters, and a not so valid url.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter_var` method with `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` flag, like this:

```
var_dump(filter_var($_POST['dlink'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED));
```

The optional `FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED` flag is for validate input with http/https

Another note about your code: there are 2 attributes `name` in the url input field.

So, you can set `$dlink` var using `filter_input` method as follows:

```
$dlink = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dlink', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please help me further by explaining how to implement this into my code above? I am pretty new to this. Thank you!